# Silverlight 5 plugin with Safari 5.1

Tags: silverlight, plugins, safari

I have a Silverlight 3 application that contains 1 code line (it's a part of real project):

```
var doc = HtmlPage.Document;
```

In Safari 5.1 (Windows 7 SP1, Silverlight plugin 5.0.61118.0) I get the Exception in this line:

Unable to cast object of type `System.Windows.Browser.HtmlElement` to type `System.Windows.Browser.HtmlDocument`

So, I don't have any access to browser DOM model.
In other browsers everything is ok.

Can somebody help me with this if it's possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, it seems to only occur on Safari for Windows with the Silverlight plugin 5.0.61118.0.  The problem seems to have been introduce with Silverlight 5.0.

Also, you cannot access: HtmlPage.Window

According to Microsoft officially Safari for Windows is not a support platform, see:
http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/Get-Started/Install/Default.aspx (click System Requirements)

In my testing I found that the issue does NOT occur in Silverlight 4 but DOES occur in Silverlight 5.

This is slightly confused because if you try to install Silverlight 4 on Safari for Windows from this link:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0

Then you end up with a Silverlight 5 installation.

I found that you use IE to visit this link then Save the download EXE, then install the EXE on Safari for Windows you will get a Silverlight 4 install and from my testing this works.  Thus, I am advising my customers who face this issue to install Silverlight 4 as described.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if this works (my application uses the navigation framework):

As the error has something to do with the `NavigationJournal` and in SL we have some control over it I just changed the Journal ownership to:

```
sdk:Frame JournalOwnership="OwnsJournal"
```

On the `MainPage.xml` where the navigation takes place in my app. In this way we lose the browsers back button/navigation but we can implement our own inside the SL app.